# vscode extension development: npm tar module + rejected promise not handled within 1 second

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, tar

I am developing a vscode extension where I need to create a tar file of the current workspace folder (all the files in the workspace folder to be tar-ed). I am using the [npm tar module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar). I have registered the command with vscode and when i run it and hit the command i get below error.

```
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'mysampletar.tar' 
stack trace: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'mysampletar.tar'
```

The code below that runs on command execution is as below:

```
export function tarit(): void {
    let workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
    let path: string;
    if (!workspaceFolder) {
        path = vscode.workspace.rootPath || '';
    } else {
        let root: vscode.WorkspaceFolder;
        if (workspaceFolder.length === 1) {
            root = workspaceFolder[0];
            path = root.uri.fsPath;

            console.log('path', path); // logs /Users/vishwakumar/vscode-ext/sample-tar

            let tarz = require('tar');
            tarz.c({
                gzip: true,
                file: 'mysampletar.tar',
                onwarn: (code: any, message: any, data: any) => {
                    console.log('code', code);
                    console.log('message', message);
                    console.log('data', data);
                }
            },
                ['/Users/vishwakumar/vscode-ext/sample-tar/dummy.txt']
            ).then(() => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage('tar file generated');
            }).then((undefined: undefined, err: any) => {
                console.log('I am error', err);
             });
        }
    }
}
```

What might be the issue? I suppose it is trying to read the tar file, how can we stop reading and where can i see the tar created ?

Could any one point me to npm tar examples ?

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error and reading documentation multiple time found the solution, here is the working code. The catch is the `cwd` option which is set to `process.cwd()` by default, You need to set this to your directory in which the folder or file you are going to archive

```
export function tarit(): void {
        let workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
        let path: string;
        if (!workspaceFolder) {
            path = vscode.workspace.rootPath || '';
        } else {
            let root: vscode.WorkspaceFolder;
            if (workspaceFolder.length === 1) {
                root = workspaceFolder[0];
                path = root.uri.fsPath;
    
                console.log('path', path); // logs /Users/vishwakumar/vscode-ext/sample-tar
    
                let tarz = require('tar');
                tarz.c({
                    gzip: true,
                    file: '/Users/vishwakumar/vscode-ext/sample-tar/mysampletar.tar', // this is the location where the tar file will be generated
                    cwd: '/Users/vishwakumar/vscode-ext/', // set current working directory to parent directory 
                    onwarn: (code: any, message: any, data: any) => {
                        console.log('code', code);
                        console.log('message', message);
                        console.log('data', data);
                    }
                },
                    ['sample-tar'], // set file list to directory which needs to be archived, this will tar all the files and folders inside recursively, 
                    () => {}        // third parameter is a empty callback, which will be called after tar completion
                ).then(() => {
                    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('tar file generated');
                }).then((undefined: undefined, err: any) => {
                    console.log('I am error', err);
                 });
            }
        }
    }
```